# How can I test and debug Xamarin Cross-Platform App on Iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing a Cross-Platform App with Visual Studio 2017 e Xamarin on Windows 8.1.

I have no problem to try and Debug the Application on Android Devices but I can not figure out how to do to test my app on Iphone.

I have a Mac with Visual Studio for Mac, Xamarin and Xcode. I can also connect the Mac with Visual Studio on Windows as A Xamarin Mac Agent.

I found guides to create a free provisioning account and I think I've managed to do it.
But I guess these guides later explain how to test, on Apple device, an app developed directly on Xcode and Mac.

At this point, I can not understand what else to do to test an app (developed on a Windows PC) on an Apple device.

Comment: Follow this doc : 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171985/how-can-i-test-and-debug-xamarin-cross-platform-app-on-iphone

Comment: what's the problem are you facing? could you describe  more detail?  got any error message, can't connect with mac or anything else？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow these guide [Device Provisioning](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/)

From my experience the importent things to do are:

Add your device to your provisioning Profile.

Create a Xcode project in order to create and maintain a "unique" Bundle identifier.

Add the bundle identifier to your Visual Studio Project.

Plug your Iphone in to your MAC.

Connect Visual Studio with your MAC.

Select your Device and run.

Each step is shown in the tutorial and its follow ups posted.
(They are for Xamarin Studio but work the same in Visual Studio)